# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'sinatra/reloader' (>= 0) in any repository

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have never had a problem with Sinatra reloader. I added it in my .rb file like this

```
require 'sinatra/reloader' if development?
```

Even the documentation validates this
http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/reloader

But I am still getting the error

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `sinatra/reloader` is part of `sinatra-contrib`.

There are two ways to install this.

1. If you're using bundler in your sinatra app, open your `Gemfile` and add this:

   gem 'sinatra-contrib'
2. If not, then just install it manually `gem install sinatra-contrib`. Then require it on your project by adding `require 'sinatra/reloader`

Answer (score 2):

There's no gem named "sinatra/reloader", but "sinatra-reloader": https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-reloader

Note: reloader is part of sinatra contrib which in turns has been merged upstream to https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra